# Populating a Spinner with results of API request

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I would like to populate a spinner with results from an API request to I have this method

```
public async Task<List<String>> LoadSection(string userID)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(PRSNCEServer + "/retrievesections.php?userID=" + userID);

        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        List<string> records = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(result);

        return records;
    }
```

At this point I am completely lost and don't know what to do to convert this to arrayadapter so that I can place the contents to a spinner.

Any thought on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

simply create the `ArrayAdapter` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/list-view/populating#using-listactivity-and-arrayadapterstring))

```
var myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, records);
```

Comment: I've also tried this before but I get the error cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>' to 'int'

Comment: ArrayAdapter has a lot of overloads, it sounds like it is using the wrong one.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.widget.arrayadapter?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9#constructors